# Make Xubuntu 13.10 look like Mac OSX

Tags: xubuntu, mac, tweak

I am trying to make my Xubuntu Saucy look like Mac OSX. Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 1):

I found a few sites:

http://xfce-look.org/content/show.php/Mac+Os++Style+for+XFCE+%2B+Slingshot+Menu?content=160569&PHPSESSID=39c2054eecf931e3e0fe922e87b4f318

http://xubuntublog.wordpress.com/2008/02/15/design-your-own-desktop-with-xfce-44-part-2/

(For ubuntu):http://langit.wordpress.com/2011/06/04/install-macbuntu-in-ubuntu-11-04/

Comment: Is there any way to add a global menu?

Comment: Global menu? Can you explain what that is? Also, sorry for the late reply.

Comment: Like in Ubuntu, the menubar of applications are not in the window itself but on the top panel, thats called Global menu.